# page redirecting to 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

i have a site called example.com in different languages

when i call example.com/en - it opens the eng version

if i write example.com/fr - it opens the french version

its a one page project. So all is catched in the index.php.
i read the url, explode it, and the i get the requested language.
everything is working fine on localmachine

on my server, if i call example.com/en - it tries to open a path, that doesnt exist and then i get a 404 error

what do i have to do so my code works like on the local machine?

Comment: Did you properly configure rewrite rules for the index.php?

Could you please share your webserver configuration and webserver error/access log?

Comment: i have htaccess, the only thing in it is RewriteEngine On

Comment: You need to at least show the code you are using. Is `.htaccess` enabled?

Answer (score 0):

To start debugging your problem, use the Developer menus of your browser ... the one that lets you see "network requests."

With it, you will very quickly be able to see *exactly what* URL was requested from the server and you'll see the `404` response being returned.

So, your first check is: *"well, *was* that the URL that I expected to be requested?"*

Then, if it was, check the server-side code to determine why it wasn't able to match that URL.

*Remember also* that, when your web-browser client requests things like `blahblah/fr`, that `/fr` bit is going to be seen *(e.g. by Apache)* as a different `<Location>`.  Carefully review the configuration documentation for your web-server of choice to make sure that it knows how to handle the URLs that it will be seeing.  (There are several ways to do this so I really can't be more specific since you don't give us any clues as to your server-side setup ...)

Answer (score 0):

Please add following to the htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Note:** If your web host doesn't allow the FollowSymlinks option, try replacing it with Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch.

This is basically configuration that works with Laravel framework. However, it should work for you as well but you need to set the path properly in the third rewrite rule.

Answer (score -1):

The typical trigger for an error 404 message is when website content has been removed or moved to another URL. There are also other reasons why an error message could appear. These include:

- The URL or its content (such as files or images) was either deleted or moved (without adjusting any internal links accordingly)

To solve these problem

- Create an error page ('404.html' or '404.php') in the root directory (if there isn’t an existing one already).
- Open the .htaccess file (or create one if needed) in the root directory, enter this in 'ErrorDocument 404 /404.html' and save the change. The error page will be generated with this code.
- To see if it’s worked, try to access an unavailable webpage and hopefully the error 404 message should appear in the browser.

Comment: i dont need a 404 page. U misunderstood my question